# Frequent wifi disconnection on ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

I have recenty installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit. My university provides cyberoam wifi connection. After 5 seconds to 1 minute, internet stops working and then wifi disconnects. I have to disable wifi and re-enable to connect with the network again.

```
lspci
```

gives following:

```
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

I have already done this

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi
sudo sh -c 'echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf'
```

On ubuntu 12.04 and windows, wifi is working fine.

**EDIT:**

I followed [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
my PCI.ID is 14e4:4365 rev 01 . So Special Case #2 . Tried steps as mentioned but still same problem.

I am facing this problem only on my college cyberoam wifi network. Problem is with ubuntu 14.04 because this network is working fine with ubuntu 12.04 and windows.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: my PCI.ID is 14e4:4365 rev 01 . So Special Case #2 . Tried steps as mentioned but still same problem

Comment: I am sorry that it didn't work. May be someone else will be able to help you. Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/609184/edit) your question and add the PCI.ID up there along with the steps you followed from previous answer (put in a link in the question), and errors if any. some people don't go through the comments.

Comment: I have same problem. Looks like it's a bug in the driver. Check this thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=193129&p=2 I'm trying to apply solution for Ubuntu.